# Excel, how to create a dynamic scatter chart that ignores blank cell

Tags: excel, graph, scatter

as the title says, I want to create a dynamic scatter chart that ignores blank cells.
For example:

```
COLUMN A
1000
2000
501

700

1000
```

The result I want is that:

[image]

http://animenod.altervista.org/Immagine.png

The column A contains a lot of values (even blank) and they are inserted through formula, and I wish that when I add a data, the chart will update without any jump or zeros, as the image shows.

Thanks in advance.

Fabio

Comment: dinamic dinamic *dynamic*

Comment: thanks for the correction :) my English has a lot to improve

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to select **Select Data...** > **Hidden and Empty Cells** > **Connect Data Points With Line**, and make sure **Show data in hidden rows and columns** is not checked. To get rid of the blank row indices, **hide the rows** with blank values.

If you cannot filter the data column manually, you can do it automatically with a macro:

1) Open a VBA Editor (ALT+F11)
2) Double-click the sheet name on the left
3) Paste this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
 If IsError(Target) Then
  Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Else:
  If Len(Target.Value) < 1 Then Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
End If
End Sub
```

Whenever you add new data, the cell will get analyzed, and the row will get hidden if the cell has no text in it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but the point of the question is that the x-coordinate of 1000 must be 5, not 7 (as shown in the picture).

Comment: @FabioMasino: You need to hide those rows with blank values in order to exclude them from the x axis.

Comment: As I said in the description, column A contains a lot of values (about 1000), so hide them is not the best solution for my problem. Besides, the cells contain formulas, then a data that once it's empty, another time can be a not-null number.

Comment: @FabioMasino: I added a macro that will hide whole rows automatically if there is an error or a cell is blank in Column A. You just have to check the column with data in your Excel sheet, amend if necessary and paste into the VBA editor.